# Can ACE2 receptors be syntesized?

Tags: coronavirus, receptor

I read that there are labs that can produces the spikes of the coronavirus. I wonder can they also synthesize ACE2 receptors or parts of them? If yes, can they be used as drugs?

Comment: It seems like Alex Reynolds gave a good answer when you asked a similar question: [https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/93416/52196](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/93416/52196)

Comment: You might spellcheck your title.

Comment: The Wuhan institue of virology [Discovery paper](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/2020.01.22.914952v2) transfected the ACE2 gene (from human, bats, mice) to HeLa cells making those transfected with human-ACE2 susceptible to SARS-CoV-2, thus proving the virus relies on this receptor for entry. Transfection means synthesizing the DNA gene in a plasmid form then adding lipofectamine to force entry into the cytoplasm then nucleus, the corresponding protein is synthesized by ribosomes and gets expressed on the cell's surface (due to a signal peptide)

Answer (score 1):

The drugs you are referring to are called receptor mimics or peptide inhibitors.  Yes, molecular mimics for human ACE2 can and have been synthesized.  Binding of these mimics to coronavirus spike proteins leads to sequestration or inactivation of viral particles.

---

**Relevant literature**:

Romano M, Ruggiero A, Squeglia F, Berisio R. [**An engineered stable mini-protein to plug SARS-Cov-2 Spikes**](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/2020.04.29.067728v1). *bioRxiv*. 2020.

Han Y and Král P. [**Computational Design of ACE2-Based Peptide Inhibitors of SARS-CoV-2**](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acsnano.0c02857). *ACS Nano*. 2020;14(4): 5143-5147.

Walls AC, Xiong X, Park YJ, *et al*. [**Unexpected Receptor Functional Mimicry Elucidates Activation of Coronavirus Fusion**](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/30712865/). *Cell*. 2019;176(5):1026-1039.e15.

Comment: Thank you very much for the exhaustive answer. Can these be effective drugs against covid and eliminate it? Are there clinical trials on the run? I see the articles are from very recent.

Comment: I'm not sure if any of the proposed drugs are currently in trials -- I'll be sure to update my answer if I find out.